# SQL Query - joining tables

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I'm quite new in query SQL and i need some help. I have information on 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
Car# | Brand (ID) | Model (ID)
123  |      23    |     47
```

Table 2:

```
ID  | Description
23  |  Honda
47  |  Civic
```

And I need to perform a select that give the output:

```
Car# | Brand (ID) | Model (ID)
123  |   Honda    |   Civic
```

Can someone help me.

Many thanks

Comment: In Table2 - how do you know what is a brand and what is a model?? This is a really weird database design ....

Answer (score 1):

You should join to table2 twice as below

```
select t1.car, t2.Description as brand,t3.Description as model
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.brand
join table2 t3 on t3.id = t1.model
```

Comment: @DarrenDavies: he's joining to **Table2** twice - just two tablse

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like:

```
select car, 
(select description from table2 where ID = table1.brand), 
(select description from table2 where ID = table1.model) 
from table1
```

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Please accept the answer so other user can see that it's the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`WITH TABLE1
     AS (SELECT
          '123' AS CAR,
          '23' AS BRAND,
          '47' AS MODEL
    FROM
       DUAL),
     TABLE2
     AS (SELECT
       '23' AS ID,
       'Honda' AS DESCRIPTION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '47' AS ID,
             'Civic' AS DESCRIPTION
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      A.CAR,
      B.DESCRIPTION,
      C.DESCRIPTION
FROM
      TABLE1 A,
      (SELECT
            DESCRIPTION
       FROM
 TABLE2,
            TABLE1
       WHERE
            BRAND = ID) B,
      (SELECT
            DESCRIPTION
       FROM
            TABLE2,
            TABLE1
       WHERE
            MODEL = ID) C;`